# Osquery Not able to run differential loggin on packs

Tags: process, difference, snapshot, pack, osquery

When running scheduled queries from packs the results are as if i am running the queries in snapshot mode i am not able to capture differentials from queries coming from pack files. I am not sure if this is a bug or a feature.

for example in my `osquery.conf`file i basically have

```
"schedule": {

   "processes": {
   "query": "SELECT * FROM processes;",
   "interval": 60,
   "removed": false
   }},

"packs": {
    "packname": "C:\\Program Files\\osquery\\packs\\test_processes.conf"
}
```

the pack file contains the same query. The scheduled processes query runs OK, it is in differential mode and i am not flooded with process logs.
The problem is with the packs that seem not being able to run in differential mode.
Every 1 minute i get the same process events being added to osquery logs

**osquery.flags**:

```
--logger_plugin=filesystem
--logger_path=C:\myproject\Data\LogFiles\osquery
--enable_powershell_events_subscriber=true
--logger_rotate=true
--logger_rotate_size=20971520
--logger_rotate_max_files=10
```

does the `--logger_plugin=filesystem` not work with packs ?

Comment: Have you got any solution? I'm facing same issue. Please share answer...